# COBOL - File Status 37 when opening sequential dataset with relative & dynamic options

Tags: file, io, cobol, zos

I'm trying to open a sequential dataset.

I get the file status 37, for which [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAE4W_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/c0925395700.htm) says:

> An OPEN statement was attempted on a file that would not support the
>   open mode specified in the OPEN statement. Possible violations are:
>
> - The EXTEND or OUTPUT phrase was specified but the file would not support write operations.
> - The I-O phrase was specified but the file would not support the input and output operations permitted.
> - The INPUT phrase was specified but the file would not support read operations.

I suspect the third, because the relevant bits of my program are :

```
  *----------------------
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
  *----------------------

   FILE-CONTROL.

 *    input file 1
      SELECT INPUT-1-FILE
         ASSIGN TO EXAMPLE
         ORGANIZATION IS RELATIVE
         ACCESS MODE IS DYNAMIC
         RELATIVE KEY IS INPUT-1-ACCESS-KEY
         FILE STATUS IS INPUT-1-FS
         .


  ****************
   DATA DIVISION.
  ****************

  *--------------
   FILE SECTION.
  *--------------

  * fichier 1
   FD INPUT-1-FILE
       .
   01 INPUT-1-LINE.
     05 filler                     PIC X(300).


  *-------------------------
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  *-------------------------

   77 INPUT-1-ACCESS-KEY           PIC 9(3) comp value 1.

   01 INPUT-1-FS                   PIC 99 value 00.


  *********************
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  *********************

       OPEN INPUT INPUT-1-FILE
       DISPLAY INPUT-1-FS
```

And the DD card in my JCL looks like :

```
EXAMPLE DD DISP=SHR,DSN=MY.DATASET.NAME
```

We're using COBOL v5, so I checked [IBM](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036733)'s [relevant docs](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/igy5lr11.pdf), but I can't find any reason that my file is not openable in input mode.

Here are my dataset's characteristics:
[image: ISPF dataset info screen]

And the result of a VSAM listcat:
[image: VSAM listcat result]

Comment: The reference you provide is for iSeries, if you're running on z/OS you want the [mainframe reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_5.1.1/com.ibm.cobol511.ent.doc/PGandLR/ref/rlpdscpf.html).  It says the same thing as what you quote for this error, but just for future reference...

Comment: Is the file a KSDS or RRDS VSAM file?

Comment: ESDS, I think. Is that the problem ?

Comment: I'm not certain, I've never done ESDS but the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_5.1.1/com.ibm.cobol511.ent.doc/PGandLR/ref/rliosdam.html) seems to talk about relative and indexed files without mentioning ESDS specifically.

Comment: Well I'll check tomorrow. Thanks !

Comment: So, not even a VSAM ? I'm not sure what that means / implies.

Comment: Clearing up a few missing points...First, the non-VSAM analog to an RRDS is BDAM, but IBM COBOL doesn't provide BDAM support anymore (you can use a subroutine in another language if you want to use BDAM in COBOL).BDAM has  efficient block-oriented direct access, very similar to RRDS. To fill another blank, a cool things about VSAM is that a given file can be accessed in different ways... generally any VSAM KSDS or ESDS can also be opened and processed by relative record number as though it was an RRDS. It's all spelled out in "z/OS DFSMS Using Datasets" if you want the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IBM docs linked in the question (page 126: FILE-CONTROL paragraph) it is said that the relative access mode is only available for VSAM files :

[image: table from IBM doc]

**Problem: the input file is currently not a VSAM file.**

**Solution: make the input file a VSAM file.**

This worked:

DD card in the JCL when creating the input file:

```
//FOO      DD DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//         SPACE=(TRK,(1000,1000),RLSE),
//         LRECL=300,
//         RECORG=RR,
//         DSN=MY.DATASET.NAME
```

The [RECORG parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/xddrecor.htm) makes the dataset an RRDS. The lines don't have an easily defined key, so I couldn't use a KSDS and I need the random access, so no ESDS either.

DD card for reading the dataset:

```
//BAR      DD DISP=SHR,DSN=MY.DATASET.NAME
```

And then in the COBOL program (in `FILE-CONTROL`):

```
       SELECT INPUT-FILE
         ASSIGN TO BAR
         ORGANIZATION IS RELATIVE
         ACCESS MODE IS DYNAMIC
         RELATIVE KEY IS INPUT-FILE-KEY
         FILE STATUS IS INPUT-FILE-STATUS
         .
```

Answer (score 2):

In your program, `ORGANIZATION IS RELATIVE` means the input file must be a relative record data set (`RRDS`) VSAM file, which can be defined using the `IDCAMS DEFINE` command. What could be happening is that if the file you open is a sequential file, you get a file status of 37. More information about `IDCAMS DEFINE` is mentioned in IBM Redbook "VSAM Demystified" section 1.5.3, '[Relative record data set](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246105.pdf#page=49)'.

You can make the input file a VSAM file with something like the following:

```
//[YOURID]  JOB ,
// MSGCLASS=S,REGION=0M,COND=(9,LT),NOTIFY=&SYSUID,TIME=(1,1)
//*********************************************************************
//* Create a VSAM
//*********************************************************************
//S1IDCAMS   EXEC  PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
DELETE   ([YOURID].P00695.VSAMRRDS) CLUSTER PURGE
DEFINE CLUSTER (NAME([YOURID].P00695.VSAMRRDS)   -
           NUMBERED                                -
           RECORDSIZE(80 80)                      -
           BUFFERSPACE(2048)                       -
           SHAREOPTIONS(4 3)                       -
           VOLUMES(SYS162))                        -
   DATA    (NAME([YOURID].P00695.VSAMRRDS.DATA) -
           TRACK(1,1)                              -
           CISZ (1024))
/*
//S2REPRO    EXEC  PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*
//VSAM  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=[YOURID].P00695.VSAMRRDS
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD *
REPRO OUTFILE(VSAM) INFILE(INREC)
/*
//INREC  DD *
XXXXXXX060ALISONALISONALISONALISONALISONALISONALISONALISONAL        ISONALIS
XXXXXXX060ALISONALISONALISONALISONALISONALISONALISONALISONAL        ISONALIS
/*
```

Comment: I think this would work, but I used a simpler solution (see my answer). Do you see any normative or technical reason to use yours instead ?

Comment: Your example seems like it will work fine as well. Glad things worked out!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a sequential dataset for read, you need to open it for Input (done!), have it in the JCL with DISP=SHR (you could try with OLD, but don't need it), and have ACCESS IS SEQUENTIAL.

ACCESS IS RELATIVE as noted by other users is for VSAM only, and your IDCAMS output shows that this is not a VSAM file. If it's just a sequential dataset, you don't need a key either.

Comment: I agree, but I needed the random access.

Comment: I don't think you can do random access on a sequential non-VSAM file, it's just READ READ READ. You can always ignore records or something I suppose if you know the format of what you want. It's not going to be efficient but would work.